# Autogenerated index file in readthedocs

Tags: svn, github, read-the-docs

I'm failing to upload to [readthedocs](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the documentation I prepared for my project and I'm trying to understand what's wrong. The documentation builds fine locally with `make html` but I cannot upload it.

The GitHub project is [ASCIIGenome](https://github.com/dariober/ASCIIGenome) and the documentation is in the [docs/](https://github.com/dariober/ASCIIGenome/tree/master/docs) dir (right now there are probably more readme.rst and index.rst files then necessary).

So I login to readthedocs and following their instructions I do:

[dashboard](https://readthedocs.org/dashboard/) `->` import a project `->` Choose: https://github.com/dariober/ASCIIGenome.git

Then for ASCIIGenome project I set:

- Name: ASCIIGenome
- Repository URL: https://github.com/dariober/ASCIIGenome.git
- Repository type: Git

Then "build" `->` build complete (passing).

But once I access the documentation at http://asciigenome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ I get to the following page saying:

```
Welcome to Read the Docs
This is an autogenerated index file.

Please create a /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/asciigenome/checkouts/latest/index.rst 

or /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/asciigenome/checkouts/latest/README.rst file with your own content.

If you want to use another markup, choose a different builder in your settings.
```

If I follow the "Edit on GitHub" link on top of that page I go to https://github.com/dariober/ASCIIGenome/blob//trunk//index.rst where I find a 404 error.

If it matters, I use SVN to interface with github.

Can you see anything wrong with my project set up?

Thank you!

Comment: Why this question has been downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears I was only impatient and all was fine. It takes a little while (~1/2 hour?) for the docs to go live even if the build is marked as "passed".

Comment: Thanks for posting this Q and A.  Mine is still at "This is an autogenerated index file." after about 10 minutes, but I'm hoping it will clear itself up too:-).