# Built in with MkDocs in Readthedocs

Tags: read-the-docs, mkdocs

I am preparing documentation using MkDocs and trying to generate the documentation using readthedocs. I followed the user guide but readthedocs does not seem to communicate with my uploaded .md files in my GitHub project. Instead of reading my `docs/index.md` file, the document generated by readthedocs says

> This is an autogenerated index file.
>
> Please create an `index.rst` or `README.rst` file with your own content under the root (or `/docs`) directory in your repository.
>
> If you want to use another markup, choose a different builder in your settings. Check out our Getting Started Guide to become more familiar with Read the Docs.
>
> © Copyright 2022. Revision `8d3f60c9`.
>
> Built with [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/) using a [theme](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme) provided by Read the Docs.

One possible issue is that the builder is Sphink instead of MkDocs, so I changed the document type to "MkDocs" in admin-> advanced setting->documentation type in readthedocs but this does not solve the issue.

I then followed the instruction in readthedocs about [getting started with mkdocs](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/getting-started-with-mkdocs.html), [import documentation](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/import-guide.html), and [configuration files](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html) for Mkdocs to set up configuration files as well as requirements but none of them work.

It would be much appreciated if anyone could help me resolve this issue.

---

I further navigated to https://shaarp-single-interface.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html.

The structure in the link above does contain all the nav panels I want but this page no longer maintains the readthedocs theme.

> SHAARP_Single-Interface
> Search docs
> Home
> Installation and Setup
> Simulation and Analytical Methods
> Input Parameters
> Output Results
> Examples

> SHAARP_Single-Interface
> Docs »
> 404
> Page not found

> Built with MkDocs using a theme provided by Read the Docs.

However, if accessing the docs using "view docs" in readthedocs, it directs me to https://shaarp-single-interface.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, which does not contain any panel I have prepared.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the building process was fine but the docs will need some time (maybe 1-2 hours) to update.

A similar issue was reported. [Autogenerated index file in readthedocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556609/autogenerated-index-file-in-readthedocs?rq=1)